# alter external table TABLENAME refresh error

Tags: external, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Error message - SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:1263389222; incident 9679362.

Trying to refresh external table on S3.  It has worked previously.

```
create or replace external table EXT_ANIXTER_WNT_PART(event_timestamp datetime as TO_TIMESTAMP(value:wirepas.wirepas.packetReceivedEvent.rxTimeMsEpoch::varchar),
source_endpoint int as (value:wirepas.wirepas.packetReceivedEvent.sourceEndpoint::int),
source_address int as  (value:wirepas.wirepas.packetReceivedEvent.sourceAddress::int),
folder varchar as (split_part(metadata$filename,'/', 1)::varchar),
message_date date as to_date(split_part(metadata$filename,'/', 2) ||'/' || split_part(metadata$filename,'/', 3) ||'/' || split_part(metadata$filename,'/', 4), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
partition by (folder, message_date)
location = @LABS_DATA.SBAS.PROLOGIS2WPEWNT_EXTWIREPAS_COM
file_format = (type = JSON)
refresh_on_create = TRUE
auto_refresh = TRUE
```

Comment: I recommend that you report the incident number to Snowflake support.  They can look it up.  Do you receive the same message every time or was that just a 1-time issue?

Comment: I would echo contacting Snowflake support. I always check the status page to make sure there is nothing happening there first (https://status.snowflake.com/).  There is not, so contacting Snowflake support for incidents is a good idea.  Please do provide the Query ID, when it was last working, whether it's intermittent, and anything else to narrow down what piece of this query is causing the incident.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the warehouse size and see if that works. Maybe the current warehouse isnt enough to read all the files (it may be due to memory not enough on the current warehouse size) depending upon the number of files in the S3 bucket.

Comment: I would expect if warehouse is too small, the execution will timeout..